# ionic form input doesn't always work Android small screens

Tags: android, cordova, input, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to create a simple app for Android:

```
  <ion-content>         
  <form name="form" id="form" novalidate>

    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">First</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="reading.firstnumber">  
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Second</span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="reading.secondnumber">
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Comment</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="reading.comment">
    </label>    

    </form>
    <p> 
   </ion-content>
```

It can take user input fine for an Android phone of fair screen size, but not ones with very small screen (320x240). On the small screen phone, it displays fine and the first input box works fine. However, the second input box only works if I place cursor into it, type into it (but what I typed is not displayed), place cursor into third input, place cursor back into second input, after that, freshly entered numbers would be displayed.

Any solution to do this?